# How to better search: replacing %20 with +

Tags: search

When I search for "asus laptop type:product" the url is "search/node/asus%20laptop%20type%3Aproduct" but how to make it like "search/node/asus+laptop+type:product".
So how to repalce %20 with + and %3A with : on Drupal 7.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for response (response is deleted, not by me).

Comment: That was me, I deleted it because I don't think what I said is actually true after a bit more research :) According to [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) `:` and `+` are reserved, but _allowed_, characters in a URI. I would wager it's the search form submission that's URL encoding the search term in the URL to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "better search", as the search works as-is. However, I think the reason it works this way is because `drupal_goto()` eventually calls `drupal_http_build_query()`, which calls `rawurlencode()`. Drupal uses this for URL query parameters. The docs for the function say it returns:

> a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits. This is the encoding described in RFC 1738 for protecting literal characters from being interpreted as special URL delimiters, and for protecting URLs from being mangled by transmission media with character conversions (like some email systems).

https://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

**RFC 1738:** https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

To change this, you could create your own module or function that does not does escape `:`. If you use an exposed view search form, it should already encode spaces as `+`.